# FastAPI awaits on task behaviour

Tags: async-await, task, python-asyncio, fastapi

Why `FastAPI` doesn't complain about the following task

```
app.state["my_task"] = asyncio.create_task(my_task())
```

not being awaited in any part of the code?

`app` is an instance of `FastAPI()` whereas `app.state` a simple dictionary.

I can even `app.state["my_task"].cancel()` in a shutdown callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `asyncio` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-never-awaited-coroutines):

> When a coroutine function is called, but not awaited (e.g. `coro()` instead of `await coro()`) or the coroutine **is not** scheduled with `asyncio.create_task()`, asyncio will emit a RuntimeWarning

Thus, it is expected that, when using `create_task()`, no warning is emmited. This is no exclusive behavior to FastAPI. You can check it in the minimal snippet below:

```py
import asyncio


async def task():
    print("foobar")


async def main():
    # task()        # Emits a RuntimeWarning
    # await task()  # Does not emmit
    x = asyncio.create_task(task())  # Doesn't either


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Edit PS: Calling the coroutine function as-is does not schedule the underlying task (and returns a coroutine object), while calling `create_task()` does (and returns a Task object). For more info, again, check the `asyncio` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).